# Can boot anything except windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, usb, windows-10

Although my bios is correctly configured i can boot anything from USB except Win installation USB i used rufus and the win program to place the iso into the USB.

I installed Ubuntu perfectly from the same USB device, the only thing i can't boot is WIN.

When i try to boot it i get the error:

```
File: boot/BCD

0xc000000e

The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors
```

Thankfully waiting for help.

Comment: Please go in to more detail on how you created your bootable USB. You said you used "the win program", where you talking about the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)?

Comment: yes and https://rufus.akeo.ie/ too. Used it for ubuntu and Gparted too and only windows isn't booting.

Comment: Did you mess with your partition table when you installed Linux? The [NTSTATUS error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) means STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE, suggesting that maybe the boot volume specified in the BCD is missing.

Comment: I have tryed several programs to recover MBR and the boot itself but nothing seems to work.

Comment: i even tried to rebuild the partition table with gparted.

Comment: Can you boot the same Win media on other computer? Maybe you have to check the boot media checksum

Comment: yes i can. I even used a friend's USB instead of mine and again everything boots except windows.

Answer (score 1):

As my CD/DVD device was wrecked i got na external 1 from my friend and it booted a  win 10 dvd perfectly.

So the problem was not totally solved but for now is good enougth.